# Add hidden field to checkboxlist

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a CheckBoxList,  in addition to checkbox and label I have to add a hidden field for each list item in the CheckBoxList. Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC? It would be helpful if you could provide samples of your code that we can reference

Comment: Also please explain WHY you need this. Perhaps you have an X/Y problem

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a [Repeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of a CheckBoxList control. On the plus side, this gives you more control over the generated HTML which might come handy anyway if you plan to access the items with jQuery; on the other hand you have to implement methods like retrieving the checked items for yourself.

The following sample shows the basic markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Item1") %>' />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Item2") %>' />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In this sample, I have bound the repeater to a list of `Tuple<string, string>` values. You can retrieve the selected items like this by iterating the items of the repeater and retrieving the CheckBox and HiddenField:

```
private IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> GetSelectedItems()
{
    var lst = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    var items = rpt.Items
        .OfType<RepeaterItem>()
        .Where(x => x.ItemType == ListItemType.Item 
                    || x.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem);
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chk");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            var hidden = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hidden");
            lst.Add(Tuple.Create(chk.Text, hidden.Value));
        }
    }
    return lst.ToArray();
}
```